# Why does the phraseme "души не чаять" have positive meaning?

Tags: этимология, выражения

OK, this question has been asked many-many times on the internet, and yet I can't google any reliable and constructive answer with a bit of documented proof.

How come the meaning of this phrase - "души в ком-то не чаять" - is "to love somebody very much"? Душа (soul) is associated with emotions, with high morality, with religion, with eternity, with the essence of a person, anyway, it has positive meaning. Бездушный is a very negative characteristics meaning that the person has no mercy and is soulless...

Everybody explains this phraseme word-by-word, saying that this was a result of either replacement of the word "чуять" by the word "чаять", or their blend. Hmm. Possible, but yet not documented. They just give links to Dal's definition of single words from it, and this is not enough for me to believe in the whole.

A very interesting point was given by Anonymous in this link :
http://rousseau.livejournal.com/83281.html

However, the person giving this opinion (about slavic roots of the phrase, meaning it all comes from pagan notions) didn't seem to be even able to construct sentences properly in Russian. This made me doubt very much that his idea could be true.

Maybe you could give me a different explanation or at least document some of the ideas listed above?

Comment: As for "язык богов и ведунов" - when you see something like that it's better to skip the rest of the post. Otherwise you can read that "радуга" is "дуга бога солнца Ра" and so on and so forth. I think he treats word атма (ātman, soul) as a-тьма (greek prefix with slavic word) and then makes a conclusion that "soul" has "no" "darkness". Purest speculation.

Comment: @Artemix, to be precise, "ātman" is a pronoun in Sanskrit and means "self", which makes the "a-тьма" explanation still more wrong.

Comment: @Artemix, I agree with you, this was too suspicious to be true. Besides, I always check the links on the internet and the information given for correctness and I didn't find anything about this meaning of the word soul. But I always think that it's my lack of education .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Предыдущий ответ был основан на моих личных соображениях по поводу значения этой фразы. В этом ответе я приведу ссылки на авторитетные мнения и источники которые мне удалось недавно найти.</sup>

На мой взгляд наиболее полным толкованием значения этого оборота, включающем не только влюбленных, супругов и т.д., но и другие отношения (например покровительство) является следующее:

> Души не чаять - безгранично любить кого-л., всячески заботиться и оберегать кого-либо. *Яранцев Р. И. Русская фразеология // Словарь-справочник. М.: Русский язык, 2001., стр. 111)*

[В. В. Виноградов](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2,_%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%92%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) приводит это выражение как пример "[фразеологического сращения](http://www.textologia.ru/russkiy/leksikologia/frazeologia/frazeologicheskie-srascheniya/730/?q=463&n=730), представляющего собою такое слитное семантическое единство, что лексические значения компонентов вовсе безразличны для понимания целого" ([см. здесь](http://www.philology.ru/linguistics2/vinogradov-77d.htm)). Такие выражения с течением времени могут сильно видоизменяться:

> ...Внешняя форма иногда бывает очень неустойчивой... Она подвержена фонетическим или эвфоническим воздействиям. Так, идиома *с боку припёка* без всяких грамматических оснований превращается в парное созвучие *с боку припеку*.

Или же выражение может "безболезненно терять свои части - одну за другой". В качестве примера Виноградов приводит выражение "ни в зуб толкнуть не смыслит (не умеет)", которое может употребляться в форме "ни в зуб толкнуть" и даже в форме "ни в зуб":

> Наконец, одно ни в зуб употребляется в том же значении; например, у Достоевского в "Дневнике писателя" (1876 г., февраль): "Человек он темный, законов ни в зуб".

Обратимся теперь к тому как же возникло это выражение. Справочная служба сайта gramma.ru так [отвечает на этот вопрос](http://www.gramma.ru/ARRM/?RG1=11&flag=1&RG2=all&page=23&PHPSESSID=4172b9e6bee814ce8ee0a224b195cfd3):

> Души не чаять - этот фразеологический оборот первоначально имел иной вид (души в себе не чуять от счастья, радости), и нынешняя его форма стала результатом смешения в речи глаголов "чуять" (чувствовать) и "чаять".

Учебный фразеологический словарь [с осторожностью говорит](http://phraseologiya.academic.ru/344/%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C) о замене "чуять" на "чаять":

> **души не чаять** Разг. Только несов. Очень сильно, безгранично любить.
>   (?) Чаять (устар.) – «надеяться, полагать, думать». Утвердился в указанной форме в результате смешения глаголов чаять и чуять – «чувствовать».

Большой словарь русских поговорок [приводит такие формы](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/proverbs/2572/%D0%94%D0%A3%D0%A8%D0%90) этого выражения:

> Души не ведать *в ком. Прикам.*
>   Души не чуять в *ком. Курск.*
>   Души не чаять (не слышать) *в ком. Народн.*
>   Души не помнить (не чуять, не чувствовать). *Пск.* 1. Быть вне себя от радости. 2. *в ком.*  Безгранично любить, обожать кого-л.

Отметим что в последнее выражение может употребляться без "в ком". В этом случае эта фраза "души не помнить, души не чуять, души не чувствовать" означает "быть вне себя от радости" не указывая на источник этих чувств (не обязательно любви и необязательно по отношению к другому человеку).

Таким образом, на основании всех приведенных материалов мне кажется что выражение приобрело современную форму таким путем:

1. Исходная форма: **души в себе не чуять от счастья/радости**;
2. Сокращение экспрессивного выражения: **души не чуять**;
3. Замена слова по созвучности: **души не чаять**;
4. Указание на источник счастья/радости (а именно любовь к кому-то): **души не чаять в ком-то**.

Загадка появления предлога "в", на мой взгляд объясняется тем что при объяснении источника этого чувства, когда "человек не чует души" а именно от любви к кому-то (а не просто *от* счастья или *от* радости), внешняя синтаксическая форма выражения диктует выбор именно предлога *в*: *[души не чаять] [в ком-то]*. (для примера "счастье в личной жизни", "нашел себя в спорте". Т.е. "в" здесь изначально не связывает "душу" и этого "кого-то", а соединяет форму "души не чаять" с дополнением, [объясняющим источник этого чувства](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/71848/%D0%92).

---

Напоследок укажу что и толкование "не чаять" как "видеть только желаемое" тоже встречается. Фразеологический словарь так [толкует это выражение](http://phrase_dictionary.academic.ru/681/%D0%94%D0%A3%D0%A8%D0%98_%D0%9D%D0%95_%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%AF%D0%A2%D0%AC):

> Имеется в виду, что лицо (Х) так эмоционально расположено к другому лицу (Y), что видит только привлекательные черты, свойства его натуры.

На мой взгляд это толкование обладает тем недостатком, что объясняя фразеологизм, смысл которого не выводится из слов, его составляющих, четко придерживается смысла, порядка и синтаксических взаимодействий между этими словами (не удержавшись, впрочем, от замены "чаять" на "чуять").

Answer (score 4):

I think, the hidden meaning is "to love somebody without taking into account their genuine soul" (which might be not so awesome as the loving person thinks). It's "добровольное самообольщение".

And - the meaning is not unconditionally positive, it's a little bit ironic. Self-possessed people normally don't "души не чают" (oh, double negation!).

Comment: I don't think that there is a hidden irony. There are many examples where parents and grand parents "души не чают" in their kids. I don't think that they feel "blind love" to them.

Comment: Also several examples of "крестьяне души не чают в своем барине": "доброты он необычайной, крестьяне в нем души не чают. [А. Н. Апухтин. Дневник Павлика Дольского (1891)]". There is no any irony in such expressions.

Comment: @Artemix - when you are talking about parents and grandparents feelings about their kids/grandkids, you actually prove my thesis about complex meaning of this idiom. Of course, they (parents/grandparents) more often love blindly than consciously. "Так природа захотела..."

Answer (score 4):

<sup>This answer was about my personal feelings and thoughts about the phraseme. In my new answer (not this one) I have posted many links to other sources that basically support my point of view. Still I think that this answer is still useful because of examples of how "soul" is used in russian and how the phraseme itself is used in literature.</sup>

Usually when the saying contains "soul" it is the speaker's soul that is talked about:

> душа не принимает; душа не лежит (к кому-чему); душа болит; за милую душу; душа ушла в пятки; сколько душе угодно (вдоволь, без всяких ограничений)

So, I think that someone "души не чает в ком-то" it is about his/her soul and not about this other person. (Actually though I never tried before to deconstruct the saying I always felt that soul here belongs to this first person.) So the saying may be rewritten as:

> Евгений (своей) души не чаял в Татьяне

Now, if we replace "чаять" to "чуять" (чувствовать) which sounds like a reasonable version, we will have:

> Евгений (своей) души не чуял в Татьяне

Also, take into account that душа according to Ushakov's dictionary except for religious meaning also means:

> ДУША́ 
>   2. В старой психологии - совокупность психических явлений, переживаний, основа психической жизни человека.
>   3. Внутренний, психический мир человека.
>   4. Свойство характера, основные черты личности, а также человек с теми или иными свойствами. Человек с открытой душой. Низкая душа. Робкая душа.
>   5. Чувство, отзывчивость, пыл.
>   8. Человек (разг.)

Which to my mind can be "translated" as:

> **Евгений забывал о себе от любви к Татьяне**

also compare other sayings:

> Евгений без ума от Татьяны
>   Евгений влюбился в Татьяну до потери сознания
>   Евгений влюбился в Татьяну до потери пульса
>   Евгений самозабвенно любил Татьяну
>   Евгений любил Татьяну до самозабвения

---

Some more thoughts.
I'm tryint to understand what can "не чуя души" mean. I recall the phrase "не чуя ног". It is used in two meanings - positive and negative:

> 1. Бежать не чуя ног - run wery quickly (as flying on wings)
> 2. Идти не чуя ног (от радости) - be so happy that feel like flying
> 3. (прийти домой) не чуя ног от усталости - barely moving feet because of being tired

As you can see - you can lose control over your legs because they refuse to function properly, or because without control they work more efficient (like when dancing, fighting or running when body better controls its movements itself than when you try to control movements using your mind or consciousness).

So, "не чуять души" can also mean - (in negative meaning) to lose the control over your mind or to lose consiousness because of exhaustion, or to lose (logic?) control over your mind because your soul (sences, emotions, feelings) performs better using it's intuition without logic explanation of all the "hows" and "whys".

Another question is: why "не чаять души **в** ком-то"?

Maybe this other person is also thought as "another soul" (compare "подушный налог" = per-soul fee, поместье и 1000 душ (=крестьян),  на улице ни души (there is nobody in the street), etc.). In this case we can recall the "жить душа в душу" phrase, which means "in harmony, understanding each other without words).

So, maybe joining these two ideas we can interpret the original saying as:

> Eugene understands all the needs and feelings of Tatyana intuitively - directly by his soul (feelings, emotions) without applying mental (logical) efforts.

It is like partial meaning of "жить душа в душу". The latter saying implies that both persons love each other, while "души не чаять" is telling about only one person of two.

Another aspect of this saying can be seen using the reference formula: "Татьяна, душенька моя, принеси книгу из библиотеки". Here a person says literaly "Tatiana, you are my soul". Using this idea we can treat the original phrase as:

> Eugene's feelings are only about Tatiana, his mind is filled only with the thoughts about her.

Other explanation of "в" is comparison with saying "видеть смысл жизни в чем-то или ком-то" (To see the sence of the life in something or someone): "Евгений видит смысл своей жизни в любви к Татьяне".  In this interpretation we don't even need чает-чует replacement:

> **Евгений не чает** (желает) своей **души** (жизни без Татьяны), потому что он видит смысл своей жизни **в Татьяне**.

or, using чает-чует replacement:

> **Евгений не чует** (осознанно контролирует чувства) своей **души**, потому что он видит смысл своей жизни **в Татьяне** (все его чувства направлены к ней).

---

Though all the examples above are about man and woman, in fact the "души не чаять" is not about romantic love. There are a numerous examples about relations between (grand)children and (grand)parants, teachers and pupils, peasants and landlords, etc.:

> Был у нас коновод по таланту, в котором Павел Петрович души не чаял. [К.С. Петров-Водкин. Моя повесть. Часть 2. Пространство Эвклида (1932)] **(очень ценит работника)**
>
> Вот, думал я, дядя Платон Маркович… до семидесяти лет прожил он рыцарем чести; доброты он необычайной, крестьяне в нем души не чают. [А. Н. Апухтин. Дневник Павлика Дольского (1891)]  **(любят своего барина)**
>
> Арина Тимофеевна души не чаяла в своей воспитаннице и сопровождала ее на прогулку и к подругам-соседкам. [Н.Э. Гейнце. Коронованный рыцарь (1898)] **(любит воспитанницу)**
>
> Есть разные любители живописи, и многие в этих артистических до манерности мазках души не чают… [И. Е. Репин. Далекое близкое (1912-1917)] **(любят искусство)**
>
> А Пантелей Прокофьевич, души не чаявший во внуках, вскочил из-за стола и, прослезившись, не вытирая струившихся по бороде слез, радостно закричал: [М. А. Шолохов. Тихий Дон. Книга четвёртая (1928-1940)] **(любит внуков)**
>
> Любили они с Василием Ивановичем друг друга умною, серьезною любовью; в детях, которых у них было мал мала меньше целых пятеро, души не чаяли. [М.Ф. Каменская. Воспоминания (1894)] 
>   **(любят детей)**
>
> Возле госпиталя на горе толстый и багровощекий английский шеф-повар Джек пас на поводке старого помойного кота, в котором он души не чаял. [Юрий Герман. Дорогой мой человек (1961)]  **(любит животное)**
>
> Взводный души не чаял в этих двух алтайцах-кумовьях, которые родились, жили и работали в самой красивой на свете, по их заверению, алтайской деревне Ключи. [Виктор Астафьев. Пастух и пастушка. Современная пастораль (1967-1989)]  **(ценит солдат)**
>
> Его знал весь гарнизон, и весь гарнизон в нем души не чаял за вечные приколы и прорывающуюся порой доброту в предоставлении тихой гавани лазарета для приятеля, у которого в роте настали черные дни и которому надо отсидеться, переждать, пока все затихнет. [Александр Терехов. Мемуары срочной службы (1991)] **(ценят сослуживца)**

Answer (score 1):

It's a phraseologism. An example of a phraseologism is 'to be between hammer and anvil'. Of course every phraseologism has it's history.

I think Russian poets think about it as for some 'reinforcing denial'. If you remove the first part 'не' you have the same sense ("to feel, to recognise somebody's soul"). The "не" adds emotional denial here.

Also 'не' is for additional *syllable*. Syllables are important in Russian - Russian tries to be euphonious. And it's more 'pleasure for hears' to start with unstressed syllable. So, this 'не' is using to create an unstressed one.

So, why does have a positive meaning? The 'не' is accentuating only, the source phrase (without the 'не') has a positive meaning.

It's agains the Russian standart grammar, but it is possible for phraseologisms.

Comment: Do you mean by 'reinforcing denial' some kind of 'double negation' (like in "[ни]чего [не] понимаю")? Are there any other examples of such "reinforcing denial"?

Comment: @Artemix No, I don't mean the double negation. I propose it's a rare case when a single negation does play a forcing part. Why? It's from the literature language, not from the speaking one. In literature we sometimes have a deal with a method when absence of something forces narrative. Am I wrong?